# You can play it for free for 2/3 more days - Usage of ''for xx more days''?

Tags: numbers, spoken-english, dates, range-inclusion

A game is free from Monday until Wednesday, meaning the game will no longer be for free after midnight on Wednesday (Wednesday 23:59).

It is around afternoon Monday and my friend asks me for how many days will the game still be free to play?

Should I respond for 2 more days or 3 more days?

1. 2 more days meaning (Tuesday + Wednesday)
2. 3 more days meaning (today + Tuesday + Wednesday)

I am not sure that if something is already happening whether I should count that in or not.

But I would go for three days because you can play it still today + 2 extra days.

How is "for *n* more days" understood? Do people use it meaning as extra days not counting today, or still including today?

Comment: How would you say this in your own native language?  Two days or three days?

Comment: I'd just go for clarity. "It's free (from now) until 23:59 Wednesday." There is no room for misunderstanding.  I have this problem with my husband. Next week, this Monday. These do not always mean the same thing to both of us. So be clear and you'll be understood. (Today is Wed, January 25th .Monday has passed. This Monday is Jan 30, next Monday is Feb. 6th.)

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on dialect, but in mine, and many others I know of, English speakers do not count the current day. In your example, I would say "2 more days."

Think of a day as a full 24 hour period. If part of a day is gone, it isn't counted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to count your days remaining

> Monday - your current day
>   Tuesday - 1 **more** day
>   Wednesday - 2 **more** days

However, the game is available for 3 days: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, the difference is using "**more** days".  One might also say on Monday

> The game is available for three days including today.

Comment: This isn't any kind of hard-and-fast rule. In most cases people will always ask for clarity: "You mean two more days **after** today?"